# display a view in admin theme

Tags: views, theming

I have a custom view for editing contents for the authors. When I'm logged in as a use with this author role this view is displayed with the 'frontend' theme. But I need it displayed in 'backend' theme.

I absolutely don't know how to get this view displayed in another theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Admin -> People -> Permissions & search **View the administration theme** check the checkbox for author role. Check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: OK, I set this permission. But the view is still displaying in frontend theme...

Comment: Does the view has **admin** as first argument of path? If not then change the page path then try.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to add "use admin theme" on a view will be available from 8.6, until then it's necessary to do some coding.

You must add a RouteSubscriber which goes through all the available routes until it finds the one (or more) you want to change, then add the '_admin_theme' = TRUE, option.

Use Drupal Console to add the RouteSubscriber (**drupal rs**) then insert the following code:

```
$admin_routes = ['view.example_page.page_1'];
foreach ($collection->all() as $name => $route) {
  if (in_array($name, $admin_routes)) {
    $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
  }
}
// or for a single route alter without a loop:
$route = $collection->get('view.view_id.display_id');
if ($route) {
  $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
}
```

And that's all you need.

More details here: https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-8-views-how-set-admin-path

Answer (score -2):

You can use [themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey). This module allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path

Comment: There's no Drupal 8 version even after three years. And no commits for a year at the time I write this.